# Django admin: restricting image uploads to JPEGs

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django admin setup where users can upload images.  The system only allows for JPEG-formatted images.  I put together a validation system to check all the images uploaded are JPEGS.  In my Images model I have an override for clean():

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True, help_text='JPEG images only', max_length=100)
    ...
    def clean(self):
        import Image

        if "images/" in str( self.image ):
            i = Image.open( "%s/%s" % ( settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.image ) )

            if i.format != "JPEG":
                raise validators.ValidationError, u'You can only upload JPEG images'
```

The problem is that this will only find an image once it's uploaded and the record is being re-saved.  If it's being created for the first time clean() function will be called before the image is saved into the media folder.

Is there a function I could override which will be able to raise an issue with a file being uploaded in the wrong format prior to the record being saved but after the file has at least been stored or is there a way of finding the temporary file location during the execution of clean()?

Comment: You may also use (my) package for [image validation](https://github.com/manikos/django-vimage).

Answer (score 0):

It's not as fool proof as actually loading up the image with PIL and checking its format, but the field has a `name` attribute that you can check when cleaning the model.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'.*\.(jpg|jpeg)$', re.I)
filename = self.your_file_field.name
if not p.match(filename):
    raise ValidationError('You must upload a JPEG image')
```

Answer (score 0):

in uploaded you can use:

```
...
import Image
from cStringIO import StringIO

self.image.open()
i = Image.open(StringIO(self.image.file.read())
...
```

for check if file uploaded:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
if isinstance(self.image.file, InMemoryUploadedFile):
   ...
```

I check all it in django 1.3